# Множественное наследование Интерфейсов

Tags: java

Допустим, два интерфейса, `Alpha` и `Beta`, реализуются в классе `MyClass`.

Что, если в обоих этих интерфейсах предоставляется метод `reset()`, объявляемый ­по умолчанию? Какой из вариантов этого метода будет выбран в классе `MyClass`? Из интерфейса `Alpha` или `Beta`?

С другой стороны, рассмотрим ситуацию, когда интерфейс `Beta` расширяет интерфейс `Alpha`.

Какой вариант метода по умолчанию используется в этом случае? А что, если в классе `MyClass` предоставляется собственная реализация этого метода?

Вопрос: приоритет отдается реализации метода в классе над его реализацией в интерфейсе. Как это понять?

Comment: Зачем вы удаляете свои вопросы? Вопрос про ссылки вполне мог получить хороший ответ и быть полезным будущим посетителям. Не надо так.

Comment: Хорошо я понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Какой из вариантов этого метода будет выбран в классе `MyClass`?

Никакой. Будет ошибка на этапе компиляции.

> С другой стороны, рассмотрим ситуацию, когда интерфейс `Beta` расширяет интерфейс `Alpha`.

В этом случае будет вызван метод из `Beta`.

> А что, если в классе `MyClass` предоставляется собственная реализация этого метода?

Тогда будет использоваться реализация метода из самого класса.

> Вопрос: приоритет отдается реализации метода в классе над его реализацией в интерфейсе. Как это понять?

Если в интерфейса есть реализация метода по умолчанию, а в классе (который реализует этот интерфейс) этот метод тоже есть, то будет вызван метод из класса.

Собственно, утверждение из Вашего четвертого вопроса – это ответ на третий.

Comment: Хорошо с этим я согласен, а вот дальше самый последний вопрос?